# Unity available from live-cd but not after upgrade from 10.10. How to fix?

Tags: unity, upgrade

Unity works perfectly fine on my Dell E6400 (Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) == Intel GMA 4500MHD?) when run from Live-CD.

However it doesn't work on my 11.04 which was upgraded from 9.10->10.04->10.10.

What might be broken/misconfigured? Is there any "trick" I can enable 3D acceleration without reinstalling complete system?

**Edit:**

Unity support test gives following output:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset GEM 20100330 DEVELOPMENT x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 7.10.2

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity supported:          yes
```

Answer (score 0):

No, your driver is ok. use ccsm (compiz config settings manager) and get rid of the conflicts, and you are good to go.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am no longer able to test your suggestion as I've done a complete re-installation due to HDD change. Now everything works perfectly fine. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

You have to activate you driver for the graphics card.
Go to *System -> Additional Drivers* and activate it.

Comment: Well, this is Intel graphics card, there is nothing to activate under "Additional Drivers".

Comment: Could you tell me which Intel graphics card you have, then i can help you better

Comment: lspci tells this: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07). Notebook specs says this: Intel GMA 4500MHD.